# Why does pointer-events behave different in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I made a simple memory game and it works fine in Firefox and Edge, but in Google Chrome it doesn't work. My version of chrome is 54.0.2840.87.

Basically the bricks get messed up when they are suppose to turn.

Here is a link to the game.

http://codepen.io/veilan/pen/PboqrZ?editors=1010

The problem is with this line

```
document.querySelector(".container").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

row 20 in the javascript file.

I use it to prevent the player from spamming bricks and break the game.

So why does this not work in Google Chrome and how can I solve it?

Two different bricks are clicked, so both should turn back to question mark. [Image to demonstrate problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxdXr.jpg)

Comment: It works in my version of Chrome.

Comment: Really? that's strange. I also tried with chrome on my samsung galaxy s6, same there doesn't work. Samsungs built in browser works fine.

Comment: It works for me as well

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? I added version number of my chrome and also added a picture to show the problem.

Comment: Yeah, mine is definitely working as it should. I have Chrome OS version 53.0.2785.154